# Where can I know the questions that I have flagged today and their status

Tags: support, flags

If I flag a question and want to know about its status, where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click your avatar in the top bar to visit your profile page. If it says "more info" at the top, next to your username, click that. Where it says "helpful flags" and then a number, click on the number. On that page, you can see your flagging history, including the status/response of each flag (whether it's still awaiting review, or was judged to be helpful or unhelpful).

Alternatively, you can just type in the URL

```
http://android.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/12442
```

but replacing "12442" with your user ID (the number that shows in all URLs about your profile).

Comment: Except the Url its good